# Flex Chrome in flex 4 SDK

Tags: air, flex4

Anyone know how to set flex Chrome in flex 4 SDK ?
coz when I use showFlexChrome, it always return error if I use flex 4 SDK.
thx

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to replace the system chrome on your windows with custom chrome?  If so, here's a decent article: http://mysticnomad.wordpress.com/2008/09/08/creating-a-custom-chrome-for-air-application/

Comment: i Mean i want to use flex chrome anyway,
i read that spark WindowedApplication had no style properties like halo. and link that u gave me, still use halo sdk.